# Executing a command and an event from an a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

My goal is to execute a command and an event from an  tag. I can get both to work separately, however I'm not sure how to merge the two together.

The command:

```
<a href="command:RunWorkflowWithArguments?workflowId=Theme_Control_Dynamic_Mapinfo_hgl&amp;themeID=1"></a>
```

The event:

```
<a href="javascript:void()" data-binding="{@event-onclick: floodButton_Click}"></a>
```

I am grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have jQuery tagged, that's the easiest way.

```js
$("#a1").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("You clicked me!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="a1">Click me</a>
```